# Is it possible to simulate HTML tag <Label /> in asp:Label ASP.NET Control?

Tags: asp.net, label, tags

I really like the HTML tag  which makes it really easy to see which label stands for which input element by checking its 'for' attribute. You know, something like:

```
    <label for="txtInput"> Enter your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtInput" />
```

Is it possible to do something similar in asp.net Label control so that I can see it stands for what input control? I could not see an attribute for that. Without extending the control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx

```
<asp:label AssociatedControlID="textbox1" runat="server" id="lblOne" />
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server" />
```

Not tested but along those lines...

Answer (score 2):

If you set the  AssociatedControlID property of the <asp:Label> control it will write out an HTML <label> instead of a <span>

Answer (score 0):

AssociatedControlID works in .net 2+ in earlier versions you need to do something like the following:

```
<label for="<%=textbox1.ClientID %>">label text</label><asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server" />
```